# Link to paragraph on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a link to a certain paragraph. So when I click my button, I go to the paragraph on that same page.

Button:

```
<a href="http://example.com/#paintings">Paintings</a>
```

Link to paragraph:

```
<a name="paintings"><h2>Paintings</h2></a>
```

My problem is that I want to adjust the view after clicking the link.
What I actually wanna do is:

1. Click Button
2. Go to the paragraph
3. Scroll down 40px

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 500px of current view??

Comment: Did you mean that you wanted some space above the paragraph when it appears? If so, why would you want a 500px top margin? That's a huge number.

Comment: 500px was just a example. I think it would be like 40px. And when de paragraph appears, I would like to have the view a little bit (like 40px) more scrolled down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using jQuery.

```
var element = document.getElementById(page);
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var elementLeft,elementTop;
var scrollTop = element.scrollTop?
element.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop;
elementTop = rect.top+(scrollTop);
var menuBar = $('#header').height();

$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: (elementTop -menuBar)
}, 1000 / 2);
```

This will make my page scroll down to the element. He will calculate the height of the element in my html and substract the height of my menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `<a name="paintings">` to `<a id="paintings">`.

```
<a id="paintings"><h2>Paintings</h2></a>
```

Comment: I think the OP meant you click on the link, it takes you to a page and automatically scrolls down 500px. Your answer just changes a name to and ID.

Comment: Exactually what Blake says. So this won't help.